# Flutter ListView not scrolling to the last added item but the one before the last

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I use a `ListView.builder` in my class to add dynamically contents to the list. I use a controller to keep the bottom focus with `controller.jumpTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent);` But I dont know why, it doesn't focus the last item but the one before the last...

here is my fonction that add an item to the list

```
if(numTeam == 1){
        _listAnnonceTeam1.add(nbrPoints);
        _controllerAnnonceT1.jumpTo(_controllerAnnonceT1.position.maxScrollExtent);
      }
```

and here is my ListView.builder :

```
child: ListView.builder(
  controller: _controllerAnnonceT2,
  itemCount: _listAnnonceTeam2.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
    return new Text(_listAnnonceTeam2[index].toString(), textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: 
    TextStyle(color: textColor),);
  },
),
```

do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do the jump in a post-frame callback to make sure the item will be included in the list:

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  _controllerAnnonceT1.jumpTo(_controllerAnnonceT1.position.maxScrollExtent);
});
```

Comment: Check if you are using the right controller, you seem to have two. Also check if the numTeam == 1 condition is not the problem.

Comment: when to set in in widget?